# friend of specialized template class (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, friend, template-specialization

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class test
{
    T y;

public:
    test(T k) : y(k) {}
    friend int a(T& x);
};

template <typename T>
int a(T& x)
{
    cout << x.y;
    return 9;
}

template <>
class test<int>
{
    int y;
public:
    test(int k) : y(k) {}
    friend int a(int& x);
};

template <>
int a<int>(int& x)
{
    cout << "4";
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test<int> z(3);
    a(z);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make a friend class of test class (in a real case, it was a operator<< of ofstream). But I have no idea how to define template friend function of specialized class.

Besides, the code above shows this compile error message;

> error C2248: 'test::y' : cannot access private member declared in
>   class 'test'

**Question added;**

Aaron McDaid works fine for me, but I was trying to overload operator<< of ofstream class.

```
friend ofstream& operator<< <test<int>> (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t);
```

I added code above to test class and

```
template<>
ofstream& operator<< <test<int> > (ofstream& os, const test<int>& t)
{
    os << t.y;
    return os;
}
```

used code above. But it looks like I cannot use os << t.y (which is *int*) I don't understand why this happens. The error message is

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**Update**: Here's a fully tested version on http://ideone.com/3KGU4. For the *Additional question*, see http://ideone.com/w0dLo)

There is a difference between ordinary overloaded functions and template functions. For example, without any reference to templates a developer can declare:

```
void f(int x);
void f(char *x);
```

Alternatively, a developer could use templates,

```
template <class T> void f(T x);
```

A major difference between them is that with ordinary functions, you must decide on a fixed set of allowed parameters in advance, and you must provide an implementation for each one. With templates, you can be more flexible.

Later in your program, it is clear that you want `a` to be a template function, not simply an (overloaded) ordinary function. But when the compiler first sees mention of `a` (around line 10), it looks like it is declaring an ordinary function. To resolve this, you must take two steps. You must declare as soon as possible that `a` is a template function, so your first line should be:

```
template <typename T> int a(T& x);
```

Then you must declare the relevant friendship. If `T` is `int`, then `a` takes a parameter of `test<int>&`, not `int&`. Therefore the two friend lines should be replaced with:

```
friend int a<test<T> >( test<T> & x); // around line 10
friend int a<test<int> >( test<int> & x); // around line 27
```

and the specialization of `a` should be:

```
template <>
int a< test<int> >(test<int>& ) // around line 30
```

**The Additional Question**

Use `ostream` instead of `ofstream` (or else include `#include <fstream>` if you will output only to files and not to `cout`). In my answer, `operator <<` is not a template, but is a normal overloaded function. I'm not sure it's possible to have `operator<<` as a template. Also, I defined the operator at the place where it is declared and declared as a friend. To be honest, I think there are other, maybe better, ways but this worked for me.

Comment: Could you please answer my additional question above

Answer (score 4):

This friend isn't a template, but an ordinary function:

```
friend int a(T& x);
```

To have a template that is also a friend, try:

```
template<class U>
friend int a(U& x);
```

---

After the discussions in the comments, perhaps I should show that I intended these declarations for the `test` class and its specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
    T y;

public:
    test(T k) : y(k) {}

    template<class U>
    friend int a(U& x); 
};

template <>
class test<int>
{
    int y;
public:
    test(int k) : y(k) {}

    template<class U>
    friend int a(U& x); 
};
```

A slight disadvantage is that this makes all the `a` functions friends of all the `test` classes, but that is often not a big problem.

Comment: Or `friend int a<>(int& x);`.

Comment: @Xeo, that is not correct. The parameter to a is `test<int>` , not `int`

Comment: @Aaron: Right, I didn't notice that. However, then Bo's answer is also wrong in that it would create ODR violations if `test` is ever instantiated with two different types.

Comment: I agree I think. I've posted an answer (g++ 4.4.3). But I'm still interested in hearing other (fully tested) solutions.

Comment: In what way is my `friend` incorrect? Note that I used a different template parameter `U` and did not use `T` in the friend declaration. It does make all `a`s friends of all `test`s, but that is just a minor inconvenience.

Comment: Bo, if you simply subsitute your `template<class U> friend int a(U& x);` in place of the first `friend` declaration, then the code will not compile. There is a lot going on in the original question, hence the need for a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: ... Could you modify your answer to make clear that both `friend` lines should be replaced with your `template<class U> friend int a(U& x);` ? Is this correct? I haven't downvoted your answer, but I'm not ready yet 100% to upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and [it works](http://ideone.com/6G6Y7)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class test;

template <typename T>
int a( test<T>& x);

template <typename T>
class test
{
    T y;

public:
    test(T k) : y(k) {}
    friend int a<T>( test<T>& x);
};

template <typename T>
int a( test<T>& x)
{
    cout << x.y;
    return 9;
}

template <>
class test<int>
{
    int y;
public:
    test(int k) : y(k) {}

    friend int a<int>( test<int> & x);
};

template <>
int a< int >( test<int> & x)
{
    cout << "4";
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test<int> z(3);
    a(z);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, template function `a` takes a parameter of `test` template class. If you want both of them to have the same template argument then , IMO you need to explicitly state that

```
template <typename T>
    int a( test<T>& x);
```

Also specialization of function `a` for `int` (`template<> int a(int& x)`) isn't useful here. You need to have

```
template <> int a<int>( test<int> & x)
```

Comment: That's failing for me if I try to use the non-specialized test. http://ideone.com/nQCFc  Link failure `prog.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `int a<long>(test<long>&)'`

Comment: I've decided I'm not going to up- or downvote anything for the time being. Things keep messing up!

Comment: .. in particular I don't understand why my original (http://ideone.com/3KGU4) works while my modification of yours (http://ideone.com/nQCFc) fails to link.

Comment: Your `template <typename U>
int a(U& x)` should be `template <typename U>
int a(test<U>& x)` in order to ensure that the non-specialized version works. See here: http://ideone.com/EtuBD

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Oooppss. yes right. I forgot it. Here is the [correct code](http://ideone.com/N31NP). And it works now.